# Internet History Eraser

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, history

If I plug my work laptop back into the work network, can they view internet history from non-network wireless use?  I've deleted the history in the standard fashion.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on what software they have installed on the computer. Because the computer is issued and owned by your employer (at least I assumed so from the way you worded your question), they might have installed any manner of software that could be used to view your past internet history, even if cleared in the conventional way. However, if they have not installed any special monitoring software, there theoretically should be no way for them to get that information remotely.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).